# Remove white space between table cells

Tags: itext

I am using ITextSharp 5.5.7.   I have the following code and everything is working.  However, I need to remove the white space between each cell.  I have tried all the suggestions found and still the white spaces are not removed.  Here is the code:

```
private PdfPTable createTable()
        {

            // Table (No border, just to hold all objects)
            PdfPTable sheetTable = new PdfPTable(1);
            sheetTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
            sheetTable.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            sheetTable.SpacingBefore = 0f;
            sheetTable.SpacingAfter = 0f;

            // Add Heading One
            sheetTable.AddCell(createHeadingOne());

            // Add Heading two
            sheetTable.AddCell(createHeadingTwo());

            return sheetTable;

        }


        private PdfPTable createHeadingOne()
    {

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

        PdfPTable headingTable = new PdfPTable(2);

        // Set widths of columns
        int[] headingTablewidths = { 50, 50 }; // percentage
        headingTable.SetWidths(headingTablewidths);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("col1row1", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        headingTable.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("col2row1", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        headingTable.AddCell(cell);

        return headingTable;

    }

    private PdfPTable createHeadingTwo()
    {

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

        PdfPTable headingTable = new PdfPTable(2);

        // Set widths of columns
        int[] headingTablewidths = { 50, 50 }; // percentage
        headingTable.SetWidths(headingTablewidths);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("col1row2", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        headingTable.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("col2row2", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        headingTable.AddCell(cell);

        return headingTable;

    }
```

**Update #1** The blue lines is the area were I need to remove the spacing:

[image]

**Update #2**,  Fixed.  Here is the code Bruno provided:

```
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(createHeadingOne());
cell.Padding = 0;
sheetTable.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(createHeadingTwo());
cell.Padding = 0;
sheetTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean when you write "the white space between each cell"? By default, iTextSharp doesn't creating any spacing, only padding. You need to do a special effort if you want to create a spacing between the borders of a cell. Maybe you're asking to take away the padding, but in that case, all the content sticks together. That's probably not what you want either. Hence the question: what do you mean?

Comment: You also have some strange things in your code. You set the border of the default cell to `NO_BORDER, but you aren't using the default cell anywhere. You define the border of all cells as `PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER | PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER`, but that's the default value. The same goes for the horizontal alignment, that's `ALIGN_LEFT` by default. And if you define the overall `Padding`, why do you also define a `PaddingTop` and `PaddingBottom` using the same value? That's strange.

Comment: Finally, why are you nesting the tables? That's not necessary, is it? Oddly enough, you set the padding of the inner tables to 0, but you don't change the padding of the outer table. I don't know by heart which effect this has, but maybe the default padding of the outer table is what you mean when you talk about the spacing between the cells. It's hard to tell. Your code is way too long for the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Bruno, per your suggestion, I removed all the uneeded items.  However I still do need to nest and call the two functions (createHeadingOne and createHeadingTwo) because separate data processing will happen in each of those functions.

Comment: OK, but where is the unwanted space? Is it the padding between the tables? If so, why don't you set the padding of the cells in the outer table to 0?

Comment: By the way, I'll remove some more strange lines from your code. It doesn't make sense to define a `SpacingBefore` and a `SpacingAfter` for an inner table. The `NO_BORDER` lines and the 100 percent width also didn't make much sense.

Comment: What you see is the padding of the inner cells.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I just uploaded a picture of the spacing I need to remove.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this like this:

```
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(createHeadingOne());
cell.Padding = 0;
sheetTable.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(createHeadingTwo());
cell.Padding = 0;
sheetTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno but now I get: 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable' does not contain a definition for 'Padding'

Comment: Thanks Bruno, see update #2 above.  I am almost there.

Comment: You don't show how you're adding those tables anywhere. I only see one `sheetTable` with 1 column and 2 rows in your code. Those two cells each have one table with 2 columns and 1 row. In your screen shot, I see much more than that, but since you're not showing where all those tables come from, I can't give any comments on your question.

Comment: Bruno, my mistake.  It is fixed and that space is ok!  Thank you!